# If I have a 5 hour layover in Frankfurt, how much time do I have to explore the city? (Quick)

Tags: airports, layovers, frankfurt

I need help on how many attractions I can cover with a layover at Frankfurt for 5 hours. It is a connecting flight from Delhi to Frankfurt, then Frankfurt to Philadelphia. The flight is happening on 8/17/19 or 17/8/19 which is very soon. 
Please help quickly.

If I have a 5 hour layover in Frankfurt, how much time do I have to explore the city?

Comment: Do you need a visa (you are travelling from India to USA)?

Comment: Agree it's a duplicate, though none of the answers mentioned taxi.  But they pretty much confirm my "not recommended."

Comment: nope, I do not a visa

Comment: IMO not really duplicate, 5 hours is doable, 3 hours is a non-starter. Budget 1 hour from that to the city, 1.5 hours in the city, 30 minutes to get back and 2 hours in the airport for a US departure. Things go faster if you have a premium ticket or status, especially for security.

Answer (score 0):

Twenty minutes to get off the plane.  Five minutes to get to the exit doors.  One minute to get a taxi.  Twenty minutes to get across the river into the city.

X minutes to see things.

Y minutes to find another taxi.

Twenty minutes back to the airport.  Five minutes to identify your gate.  Z minutes in the security line.  Five minutes to run to your gate.  Gate closes ten minutes before take off.

X = 5:00:00 minus 1:26:00* minus Y and Z.

Not recommended.  Better off enjoying the artwork in the airport or a short walk outside.

*numbers approximate, but Y and Z unpredictable.

Comment: I don’t know Frankfurt, so there MAY be attractions between the airport and the city.

Comment: You forgot the time for immigration, as an Indian or US citizen there will be something of a delay, can be a serious one if it is busy. And the exit 'immigration' to get the 'left' stamp.

Comment: Good catch, @Willeke.  And it probably will be busy—at best, the line will contain many of the people that made it take time to get off the plane.

Comment: And the OP is presuming their plane will actually be on time...

Comment: And presuming nothing like the long delays today all over USA when the CBP computer network crashed.